# views for Django flatpages?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-flatpages

I use the following to determine the template on a pattern that matches the index page, in which I determine which template to load based on if it's an AJAX request:

```
def home(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = "ajax.html"
    else:
        template = "index.html"

    entries = posts.objects.all()[:10]
    return render_to_response(template, {'posts' : entries}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, I don't have anything regarding flatpages mentioned in my views.py, how can I do a similar request.is_ajax() check for the templates of flatpages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', 'Alpha.blog.views.flatpage', {}, 'flatpage'),
```

views.py:

```
def flatpage(request, url):
    try:
        if url == '':
            url = 'home/'
        flatpage = FlatPage.objects.get(url="/%s" % url)
    except:
        pass

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = 'pages/ajax.html'
    else:
        template = 'pages/default.html'

    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    context_instance.autoescape=False
    return render_to_response(template, {'flatpage': flatpage}, context_instance)
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the FlatpageFallbackMiddleware as well, if you're handling this yourself. You also want to make sure that your URL pattern is the very last one in your urls.py, and know that if you were ever serving flat pages based on 404s raised in another view, then that won't work anymore.